# Two column dynamic layout

Tags: css

I have several **boxes** containing the following!

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="anything.png" /> <!-- The width is dynamic -->
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the text floats to the left after the image. I want it to go straight down, as I've marked it in the following image:

---

[image: Example]

---

This is the way it should look like:

[image]

I do not want to use `tables` or `javascript`. I can't use margin-left for the box-text, because the **width** of the image is **dynamic**.

Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: tried to add display:block; to the div with the class of box-text ?

Comment: you want to all text should be below of the image. Am I right?

Comment: display block does not work.
No i want to float it to the right and go straight down.

Comment: Thank's Prahalad for your editing. I will remember to outline the most important words the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use tables, but make the `<div>`s act like the cells of a table, then make the inline content vertically aligned to the top:

```
​.box{display:table}
.image{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
.box-text{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;}
```

[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/WdYjG/1/)

Answer (score 3):

try using display: table for your box class and display: table-row for both image and box-text classes. Then align content using vertical-align: top on image and text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
.image { float: left; }
.box-text { float: left; }
```

Also you may want to stop floating elements after `box` div, so don't forget some clean up in the end:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: float:left does not work, because I'd have to give the .image and .box-text a fixed width.

Comment: But your question says that `.image` width is dynamic, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an fiddle which shows how to acheive this layout: http://jsfiddle.net/X7j4P/

```
.box {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image {
    float:left;
}
.image img {
    width:300px;
}
.box-text {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
}
p {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer, but this does not work, because the width of the image is dynamic